# Comments not Displayed in tableView

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cocoa-touch, parse-platform

In the app I'm working on, it allows users to post on the main timeline and other users can comment on that user's post, so I've been trying to display the comments in the tableView, but it's not showing. I have already confirmed that the data is being posted to parse, so on that end it's working as expected, but when it comes to display the comments, I cannot seem to get it to work. I'm using this function to display the comments:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("commentCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CommentTableViewCell
    cell.commentLabel?.text = comments![indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

is anything wrong with my code? or is there another way to display the comments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that I was missing:

```
UITableViewDataSource
```

in my class, so this fixed it:

```
class DetailViewContoller: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITextViewDelegate {

...
...
...

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
commentTableView.delegate = self
commentTableView.dataSource = self
```

Answer (score 0):

where is the code to retrieve the comments? make sure you are calling "self.tableView.reloadData()" after the for loop.

the way I generally retrieve information from parse is like so:

```
    func query() {
    var query = PFQuery(className: "comments")
    query.orderByDescending("createdAt")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (caption2: [AnyObject]?, erreur: NSError?) -> Void in
        if erreur == nil {
            // good
            for caption in caption2! {
                   self.comments.append(caption["<YOUR COLUMN NAME WHERE COMMENT IS STORED IN PARSE HERE>"] as! String)



            }
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
        else {
            // not good
        }
    }
   }
```

Add this function to your class. Then change this:

```
     func reply() {
post?.addObject(commentView!.text, forKey: "comments")
post?.saveInBackground()
if let tmpText = commentView?.text {
    comments?.append(tmpText)
}
commentView?.text = ""
println(comments?.count)
self.commentView?.resignFirstResponder()
self.commentTableView.reloadData()
 }
```

to this:

```
      func reply() {
post?.addObject(commentView!.text, forKey: "comments")
post?.saveInBackground()
if let tmpText = commentView?.text {
    comments?.append(tmpText)
}
commentView?.text = ""
println(comments?.count)
self.commentView?.resignFirstResponder()
self.query
 }
```

Comment: I just added my whole class

Comment: Okay I added that function and I modified the `reply()` function but I get errors in `self.comments.append(caption["comments"] as! String)` saying that **cannot invoke append with an argument of list type string** and error here: `self.tableView.reloadData()` with **cannot invoke reloadData with no arguments**

Comment: I can fix the `reloadData` error by instead of using `tableView.reloadData()` I can use `commentTableView.reloadData()`

Comment: at the top, instead of var comments: [String]?  try var comments = [String]()

Comment: I read that the error: **cannot invoke append with an argument of list type string** happens because is normally called when trying to append to an optional array

Comment: So I changed `var comments: [String]?` to `var comments = [String]()` and modified whatever was needed to modify, and when I ran the app, the  comments are still not being displayed, so I tried to reply to a post and it crashed saying **Could not cast value of type '__NSArrayM' (0x38449ac4) to 'NSString' (0x385f50b0)**